# timestamp from both date & time inputs and compare php

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I've been struggling to get an exact answer for this question. There are many that are close to what I'm wanting but seem to still be just off. The application of this is to ensure that a booking can't be made for a past date.

I have a form which has an input for time & another for date. Firstly, I wan't to take both of these inputs & convert them to a timestamp.

This code returns nothing

```
$time_date = sprintf("%s %s", $pDate, $pTime);
$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia d/m/Y', $time_date);
$stamp = $objDate->getTimestamp();
echo $stamp;
```

So I've have tried using something like this

```
$pDate  = $_POST['pDate'];
$pTime  = $_POST['pTime'];
$full_date = $pDate . ' ' . $pTime;
$timestamp = strtotime($full_date);
echo $timestamp;
```

But for some reason it is returning an incorrect timestamp. (i've been using an online converter) 02/06/2014 as date & 12:23am as time, is not 1401625380. This according to the converter is Sun, 01 Jun 2014 12:23:00 GMT. 
Does someone have working code for returning a timestamp of both time & date inputs?

Secondly I want to compare this timestamp with a specified one & check to see if it is greater than. I've created a timestamp for my timezone with this

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));
$cDate = $date->getTimestamp();
echo $cDate;
```

and will simply have an if statement which compares the two and echos the appropriate message. 
I feel as though there are multiple question on here that are **ALMOST** what I'm wanting to achieve but I can't manage to get them working. Apologies for the **near** duplicate.

Note: I'm using ajax to post form data (if this could possibly interfere).

Comment: "02/06/2014" is 6th of february at least in one date format. I'll suggest using 'Y-m-d H:i' format for use in strtotime.

Comment: What does a var_dump of $pDate and $pTime look like?

Comment: string(10) "2014-06-05" string(5) "16:23"

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snipped is correct. Assuming it's in datetime format (Y-m-d H:i:s).

[From php manual about strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

*Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter.*

Check your PHP default time zone with date_default_timezone_get() function.

To compare two dates, be sure they both are in same time zones.

For datetime inputs I personally use [jQuery UI timepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) addon.

Answer (score 0):

you receiving the time and date in string format - so i don't believe the ajax can interfere.
as for your question:
first of all - find out what is the locale timezone of your server. you can do it by this function: [date_default_timezone_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php).
if the answer doesn't suit you - you can use its "sister": [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), and change it to whatever value you need (like 'Pacific/Auckland' - see the documentation there). it is also recommended to return it to the original value after you finish your stuff.

i believe fixing your locale timezone will solve your issue.

Comment: I've set the timezone at the beginning of the php file to pacific/auckland & it returns the correct timezone as well as unix timestamp